# How to install a (sub)package of a virtual package in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

### Setup

I am working with Yocto 3.4 "Honister" and I utilize the following layers:

- openembedded-core ([refspec: yocto-3.4](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/tree/yocto-3.4))
- meta-openembedded ([refspec: f632403d1800363ac63a1ad5543278b82c659832](https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/commit/?id=f632403d1800363ac63a1ad5543278b82c659832))
- meta-raspberrypi ([refspec: 1584bddcf31f4bf3acc2304aa8dae927e8bec970](https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi/commit/?id=1584bddcf31f4bf3acc2304aa8dae927e8bec970))

I created my own `distro.conf` which essentially looks like this:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES = "acl argp ext2 ipv4 ipv6 largefile opengl pam usbhost xattr zeroconf systemd vfat wayland"
DISTRO_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "packagegroup-core-boot"

INIT_MANAGER = "systemd"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_base-utils = "packagegroup-core-base-utils"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils = "packagegroup-core-base-utils"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils-hwclock = "util-linux-hwclock"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils-syslog = ""

IMAGE_LINGUAS ?= "de-de en-us"
GLIBC_GENERATE_LOCALES ?= "de_DE.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8"
```

### Question

My goal is to have libGLESv2.so installed distro-wide. The `mesa` recipe provides the lib like this:

```
...
PROVIDES = " \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'opengl', 'virtual/libgl', '', d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'gles', 'virtual/libgles1 virtual/libgles2', '', d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'egl', 'virtual/egl', '', d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'gbm', 'virtual/libgbm', '', d)} \
    virtual/mesa \
    "
...
PACKAGECONFIG:class-target ??= "${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'wayland vulkan', d)} \
                   ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'opengl', 'opengl egl gles gbm dri gallium virgl', '', d)} \
                   ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'x11 opengl', 'x11 dri3', '', d)} \
                   ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'x11 vulkan', 'dri3', '', d)} \
                   elf-tls \
           "
...
PACKAGES =+ "libegl-mesa libegl-mesa-dev \
             libosmesa libosmesa-dev \
             libgl-mesa libgl-mesa-dev \
             libglapi libglapi-dev \
             libgbm libgbm-dev \
             libgles1-mesa libgles1-mesa-dev \
             libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa-dev \
             libgles3-mesa libgles3-mesa-dev \
             libxatracker libxatracker-dev \
             mesa-megadriver mesa-vulkan-drivers \
             mesa-vdpau-drivers \
            "
...
```

For raspberry-pis the file `rpi-default-providers.inc` sets the default providers:

```
...
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgles2 ?= "${@bb.utils.contains("MACHINE_FEATURES", "vc4graphics", "mesa", "userland", d)}"
...
```

Therefore the connection from the virtual package to the concrete provider should be setup properly. But (obviously) this does not deploy the library into the final rootfs. How can this be done?

### What I tried so far

The obvius way to go would be to just install the package by name in the `distro.conf` with something like this:

```
...
DISTRO_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "libgles2-mesa"
...
```

This works, but honestly this approach feels kinda wrong to me. In my opinion this bypasses the whole concept of virtual packages. Or am I wrong on that?

Additionally for testing purposes I installed weston to the image. This adds libGLESv2.so to the rootfs and I tried to resolve why this is happening (and utilize the same approach for my problem) but I cannot figure it out. From the `weston` recipe the relevant parts for the problem seems to be those:

```
...
DEPENDS += "wayland wayland-protocols libinput virtual/egl pango wayland-native"
...
# Weston on KMS
PACKAGECONFIG[kms] = "-Dbackend-drm=true,-Dbackend-drm=false,drm udev virtual/egl virtual/libgles2 virtual/libgbm mtdev"
# Weston on Wayland (nested Weston)
PACKAGECONFIG[wayland] = "-Dbackend-wayland=true,-Dbackend-wayland=false,virtual/egl virtual/libgles2"
...
```

This adds all the virtual packages to the list of DEPENDS, but when I do that (e.g in my image recipe) I see mesa being build but the library is not deployed to the rootfs. I fail to see how `libgles2-mesa` is pulled here.

Comment: In order to fully understand, when you say "My goal is to have libGLESv2.so installed distro-wide." do you mean you want EGL support distro wide? because installing a file "distro-wide" doesn't really make sense, it *is* distro wide. I think you want EGL support on every possible package.

Comment: @ArielM. Yes I guess your description fits what I want to achiev

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every package's recipe is correctly configured (you can assume this for Yocto's, check your own), in order to enable GLESv2 across the entire compilation you need:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES += " gles2"
```

either on the image recipe or in `conf/local.conf`